# Why is my tableview header showing up off-center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

iPhone 6 simulator: [image: image 1]

iPhone5 hardware: [image: image2]

Channel Header:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    l.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    l.backgroundColor = BGC;
    l.text = title;
    [self addSubview:l];
    return self;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    ChannelHeader *h = [[ChannelHeader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tv.frame.size.width, 44) title:[self titles][section]];
    return h;
}
```

Why is my tableview header's textfield showing up off center?

Tableview frame in iPhone6 sim:

```
<UITableView: 0x7fce2c821a00; frame = (0 0; 414 736)
```

EDIT:

so I changed my simulated nib size from "iPhone 6" to "inferred", and the view boundaries grew. I stretched my UITableView to fit the bounds and now  the text is even *more* off-centered. So somehow it's getting the wrong values for its frame..

Comment: are you asking why the 'Hi' is left aligned? Also is the above initWithFrame from a subclassed UITableViewCell class definition?

Comment: No, I'm asking why the tableheader is aligned with the center being to the right of the true center

Comment: are you using a storyboard to generate your table and also not setting constraints on the storyboard?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout in your storyboard/XIB? If so the Autolayout is resizing your ChannelHeader. Also check the frame self.tv.frame. it may be also incorrect

Comment: I'm using a NIB. I disabled autolayout and I still get the same issue and tableview frame is: tv
<UITableView: 0x7fce2c821a00; frame = (0 0; 414 736)

Comment: Could you `NSLog` your `ChannelHeader` frame?

Comment: Ah yup, it was showing 600 width.. I just set my frame manually to screen size and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your frame for iPhone 6 is wrong.

**iPhone 6** screen size is **375 x 667** points.

**iPhone 6 plus** screen size is **414 x 736** points.

Therefore, if you are running the application on iPhone 6 simulator and tableView frame is giving you iPhone 6 plus boundaries, then that is the error. Your header and UILabel is being rendered correctly according to the given frames.

So if you run your application in iPhone 6 plus simulator, you will get correct results.

[More info on frames.](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified)

**Solution:**

If your setting your tableView through nib, and if you are using AutoLayout then you need to apply **constraints** accordingly.

If you have disabled AutoLayout then apply proper resizing masks to your tableView, i.e. **Flexible Height** & **Flexible Width**

---

Also, it would be a good practice, if you take values of the tableView frame provided by the delegate method instead of referring to the tableView property.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    ChannelHeader *h = [[ChannelHeader alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), 44) title:[self titles][section]];
    return h;
}
```

*Note*: This is just a piece of good practice and it doesn't effect the logic or the answer.

Comment: What constraints do I need to add? I'm just using a standard nib.. (edited question with constraint image)

Comment: Ok, select your `tableView` then go to **Editor > Pin > Leading Space to Superview**, then in your attribute inspector check the constraint's **constant** is set to 0, if not then set it to 0. Repeat the same process i.e. again select your tableView and apply **Trailing Space to SuperView**, **Top Space to SuperView** and **Bottom Space to SuperView**

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I await your response on the above comment, I'm quite certain I know why you are having an issue.

If you want to create UITableViewCell(s) which have centred labels there are really only two correct ways.

Either:

- Subclass `UITableViewCell` and create a custom subclass which has an indigenously centred label.
- Set the `NSTextAlignment` of the regular `UITableViewCell` textLabel control to centre in cellForRowAtIndexPath like so:         `cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .Center`.

To change the header text alignment, you should do something like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     UILabel * sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     sectionHeader.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
     sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
     sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   return sectionHeader;
}
```

Comment: This is correct but I'm asking about why my Tableheader is showing off center

Comment: Ahh, I understand, please check my updated answer, if the above initWithFrame is from a UILabel subclass then I'm not sure why it isn't working. You could try setting the background colour of the headerView to an obvious colour like red, to check why it isn't working.

Comment: It's a UIView that functions as the table header view